# Infinite noncyclic groups with abelian automorphism group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there any infinite noncyclic group whose automorphism group is abelian..can we find a sufficient condition for infinite group to have an abelian automorphism group
Thank you

Comment: Group of integers?

Comment: @Mare obviously not. A group with abelian automorphism group has to be 2-step nilpotent.

Comment: Every cyclic group has abelian automorphism group..i am seeking for a non cyclic infinite group or a sufficient condition that makes an infinite group to be a Miller group

Comment: @YCor Sorry, stupid error by me. I deleted the comment.

Comment: Additive group of rationals has abelian automorphism group too, and is not cyclic.

Comment: @YCor So presumably you consider abelian groups to be $2$-step nilpotent? (Perhaps $n$-step nilpotent does not mean the same as nilpotent of class $n$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt of course I mean $n$-step as a variety, not as the complement of the $(n-1)$-step-nilpotent variety in the variety of $n$-step nilpotent groups. In the same way I consider abelian groups as metabelian groups.

Answer (score 7):

The finite abelian groups that can be the automorphism group of an infinite abelian group have been classified by Fournelle in [[Finite groups of automorphisms of infinite groups II, J. of Algebra 80, 1983, 106 - 112, Theorem 1.2]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383900200):

> There is an infinite abelian group $A$ with $Aut(A) = G$ for a finite abelian group $G$ iff $G$ is of even order and is a direct product of cyclic groups of orders 2, 3, and 4 with the property that if $G$ has an element of order 12 it also has an element of order 2 that is not a sixth power.

Examples of torsion-free groups $A$ with $Aut(A)=G$ for $G$ as above are constructed in [Fuchs: Infinite abelian groups II, Chap. XVI, Sect. 116] in  examples 1, 2 and Theorem 116.2.